# Disable attachment delete button in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

is there any way to disable work item attachment delete button based on certain user or group?
Pleas suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes. Check out below steps:

1, Go the **Project settings**-->**Project configuration** under **Boards**-->**Areas** tab--> Click the 3 dots of the selected Areas path -->Choose **Security**

[image]

Select the root area path to disable the delete permission for all workitems. Or select a sub area path to disable the permission for those workitems under this area path.

2, In the search box **Search** for the user or group you want to restrict the permission of deleting workitem attachments for the work items in this Areas path. Then deny the `Edit work items in this node` permission

[image]

Then the user or group will not be able to delete the workitem attachments.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If we set the permission to deny, this will disable all the activities related to work items. Totally unable to edit at a particular node. I'm looking for something different where user should have permission to edit/update the work item. User can also add the attachment but should not delete it. Only admin should have delete attachment permission. Suggest if this could be handled with an extension.

Comment: I afraid there isnot an extension available now to hide the delete button for some users/group. You can [submit a user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to Microsoft development team, hope they will support configuring attachment permission in the future sprint.